# How to submit the Facebook app for review?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am working on an app that needs to update a Facebook user's status using a custom composer in an Android app. Also, I would like to get the user's videos to show them inside the app itself. I believe I'll need the following permissions to achieve the desired features.

```
publish_actions

user_videos
```

To get those permissions, I need to submit my app for review. I have prepared the required stuff for that such as, steps to reproduce and screencast of mobile app, to give an idea of the features working. Facebook also requires the APK to be uploaded along with the submission. But, the problem is I don't have the required permissions for now, so how will I demonstrate the exact feature up and running in the Android app? Without the APK, I won't get the app reviewed.

Is there any way to get the required permissions for some users, so that I'll be able to demonstrate in the screencast? Please help.

PS: I tried to add some Test Users but they don't seem working fine.

Comment: You can ask any user that has a role in the app (admin/developer/tester) for any permission, reviewed or not. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#faq_180362122361921

Comment: Thanks @CBroe! I was able to get right direction from here.

Answer (score -1):

Follow these simple steps to submit.

```
1.Open your app in facebook console account.
2.Go to App Review,in app Review click the button Start a submission.
3.On Left List of Items will be displayed.
4.Select Items for Review
5.You have to Add Notes for Each Permission(Add the text to explain why u need that particular permission or add a video clip or
Screenshots.
*NOTE*:--make your note in such a way that they can understand your requirement clearly,otherwise they are not going to approve it.
6.AtLast Press the Save Button for submission.
```

Guys You need to wait for minimum 1-2 days to get approval.
You will get Alert in the Alert Tab on Facebook Console account of your app,
once you will get the approval,then good to go.
Hope it will help someone.